# Print multi-octet character in c

Tags: c, printing

I'm trying to print some special characters in console but I have a problem :

If I want to print '│' for example, I will get '^B' in the console.

the decimal value of '│' is 9474 and I realised that this character is defined on 3 octet.

If I just do a `printf("%c",9474)`, I'll get '^B' again

One way I thought of solving that problem is to convert 9474 in bytes to then print each octets to have my │ but I don't have a clue on how to do that.

Comment: With `"%c"` you will print a `char`, and that value is to large to be a `char` on most standard platforms (where `char` is an 8-bit byte). Perhaps you should consider wide characters? The `wchar_t` type?

Comment: Have you read this: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html Also, C isn't the language of my choice for text processing, I'd look at Python.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I realised that. Is that a %something that prints multiple octets characters?

Comment: [This `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%c` expects the corresponding argument to be an `int` that is converted to *unsigned char*. `9474` is `0x2502` in hex - conversion to `unsigned char` on platforms with `#define CHAR_BIT 8` keep just the least-significant byte, here `0x02` which is the ["Start of text"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0002/index.htm), which is echoed on terminals as Control-B, aka `^B`.

If your locale environment has been set properly, at the beginning of the program, minimally set `LC_CTYPE` to the  system locale; then print the character using `%lc`; for maximal compatibility, cast the character to `wint_t`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) {
    if (! setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")) {
        perror("Unable to set the locale");
        exit(1)
    }
    printf("%lc\n", (wint_t)9474);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Oups, multibyte character processing in C is not that easy and requires... bytes analysis. You character is the unicode character U+2502 *BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL*, because 9474 is 0x2502.

When you do `printf("%c",9474)`, you print the low order byte of the int value 0x2502, so it is the same as `printf("%c",2)` which explains why you get a <kbd>Ctrl B</kbd> representation as `^B`.

As your initial character has a code > 256, it cannot fit in a `char`, so you need to store it in a `wchar_t` (it is < 65736 so it will fit in a `wchar_t`). You can the simply print it as a single wide character:

```
printf("%lc", 9474);
```

and you should get the correct `│`, provided your locale is coherent with your terminal charset.